# Can I create a dynamic number of rows in TabView through an iteration?

Tags: dynamic, variable-definitions, dialog-window

I have written code, with the help of stackoverflow of course, and I want to make it user friendly so that other people in my lab can use it. I'm playing with DialogCreate and similar functions. I want to do something like this so far:

```
   CreateDialog[TabView[{
   "General" ->
    Column[{
      Row[{TextCell["Project Name:"], InputField[Dynamic[Project]]}],
      Row[{TextCell["Number of Wells:"], InputField[Dynamic[num]], 
        Button["Set", DialogReturn[num]]}]}],
   "Row Selection" ->
    Column[{Do[
      Row[TextCell["Well " <> ToString[i] <> ":"], 
      FileNameSetter[Dynamic[Evaluate[Symbol["w" <> ToString[i]]]], 
     "Open"]], {i, 1, num}]}]}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
 ]
```

I want to dynamically create more rows based on the input of "Number of Wells" within the same dialogbox but in a different tab. Is anything like this possible or some sort of alternative?

Comment: Code doesn't run as posted.  Looks like you may need to define "Project".  Hard to tell without the example running.

Comment: Check the answer below, it worked well. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CreateDialog[
  TabView[
   {"General" -> 
     Column[{Row[{"Project Name:", InputField[Dynamic[project]]}],
        Row[{"Number Of Wells:", InputField[Dynamic[num]], 
        Button["Set", DialogReturn[num]]}]}], 
   "Row Selection" -> 
     Dynamic@Column[
      Table[Row[{"Well " <> ToString[i] <> ":", 
         FileNameSetter[Dynamic[Evaluate[Symbol["w" <> ToString[i]]]],
            "Open"]}], {i, 1, num}]]}, 
   ControlPlacement -> Left]]
```

[image]

**Update:** There are two problems in the original code:

First, regarding the use of `Do`, unless an explicit `Return` is used, the value returned by `Do` is `Null`. Please see the docs on `Do` and the tutorial [Loops and control structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LoopsAndControlStructures.html). For example

```
 t = 2; Do[t = 1 + k t, {k, 1, 2}]
```

does the calculation to change the value of `t` but does not return anything. You need to explicitly `call` the new value of `t` to see the effect of what happened inside `Do`:

```
t = 2; Do[t = 1 + k t, {k, 1, 2}];t
(* which gives the result: 7 *)
```

So, to get your code working with `Do`, you need to do something like:

```
"Row Selection" -> 
  Dynamic@Column[tt = {};
  Do[AppendTo[tt, Row[{"Well " <> ToString[i] <> ":",
   FileNameSetter[Dynamic[Evaluate[Symbol["w" <> ToString[i]]]], 
    "Open"]}]],
   {i, 1, num}]; tt]
```

which, of course, is not as clean as the alternative with `Table[...]`.

Second,  regarding why `Dynamic[Column[ ...]]` is needed please see the 
tutorial [Introduction to Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html), in particular, the section `Where Should Dynamic Be Placed in an Expression?`

By the way, `@` is short form of [`Prefix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prefix.html), and `f@x` is an alternative syntax for `f[x]`, that is, `Dynamic@Column[.....]` is the same as `Dynamic[Column[...]]`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much kguler.

Comment: So can you explain what adding the @ does that makes this work? I'd like to learn how you knew how to do that.

Comment: @tquarton, thank you for the accept. Please see the update with links to useful material.